# Multiply and Sum Data from 2 tables based off of Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In one formula, I am trying to multiply and then sum up data in 2 different tables based off of criteria selected for both tables.

So, if the user picks data from column 1 in the first table but column 3 in the second table, I want to use the corresponding amounts.  I tried using Sumproduct but couldn't get it to work.

I used =SUMPRODUCT(ExpenseBase * ExpenseMultiplier*(ModelTypeBase=Type)*(MultiplierTypes=Multiplier))

ExpenseBase is the data in table 1, ExpenseMultiplier is data in table 2, ModelTypeBase is the top labels in table 1 and MultiplierTypes is the top labels in table 1.  If I choose X and A, I get the right answer, but if I choose B in the second table it goes to 0.

Base Tables

[image]

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S72yY.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDyeZ.png)

Comment: I tried adding a picture of the data and it said it was added but it is not on my post.

Answer (score 2):

Use INDEX to return the correct column

Capital:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(INDEX($B$3:$D$10,0,MATCH($B$17,$B$2:$D$2,0)),INDEX($G$3:$I$10,0,MATCH($B$18,$G$2:$I$2,0)))
```

Then for Expense we change the lookup ranges:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INDEX($B$12:$D$14,0,MATCH($B$17,$B$2:$D$2,0)),INDEX($G$12:$I$14,0,MATCH($B$18,$G$2:$I$2,0)))
```

[image]